# SOQL to pull Public Link & Library Name for Files

Tags: soql, files, sales

I've asked the question on the Trailblazers forum with no success of answers. Seems people are not into SOQL that much there.

I'd like to pull a list of Files names and Public Link URLs filtering only one Library name.

I've played around and tried different approaches but because the Salesforce files have so many related objects, it’s very complicated.

I've seen suggestions where the ContentVersion is queried and the ContentWorkspace is subqueried. But really not sure about filtering that down.
Also how can we get the ID for a Library?

Finally, I'd like to write this query only in SOQL not in Apex.

Comment: welcome to SFSE!  Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community.  What have you tried?  Hint:  `ContentWorkspaceDocument`  is a junction between `ContentDocument` and `ContentWorkspace` (the library). `ContentDocument` has a lookup to (latest) `ContentVersion`

Comment: Hello. Thank you for those details.